# How to prepare a statement the right way?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently writing a CMS and I want to prevent SQL injection.

I have the variable $url_variable which is a $_GET. Now I want to prepare the statement and search for the $url_variable in my table.

```
$stmt = $db_connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM $url_table WHERE url = ?");
$url_variable = $stmt->quote($url_variable);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $url_variable);
```

Now my questions: Is this code above right? Do I need the quote? And is it safe from any SQL injection?

Comment: Create an array with all valid table names, then check if `$url_table` exists in the array. If it is - use it, otherwise - do not.

Comment: You should **not** use `$stmt->quote` when you're using `bind_param`. Binding parameters takes care of everything.

Comment: $url_table is already safe and set beforehand. I want to know how to secure $url_variable so I can execute it without the risk of an SQL injection.

Comment: @Barmar: So if I delete the second line, it should be good to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `bind_param` protects those parameters from SQL injection. You don't need `$stmt->quote`, and it can actually cause the query to fail. It will add escape characters, and when you use `bind_param` it will search for these characters literally.

Answer (score 3):

You should create a whitelist for your $url_table variable and check if the table name is in your whitelist before you use it in your query. For example, you can do so with a simple if check:

```
if ($url_table == 'allowedTableName' || $url_table == 'anotherAllowedTableName') 
{

    $stmt = $db_connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM $url_table WHERE url = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $url_variable);
    //........
}
else {
    die('Illegal table name provided');
}
```

You shouldn't quote your variable that is bound, you are good to go with the prepared statement!

Answer (score 1):

In this code:

if you use Url_Variable by method GET can be added strip_tags or htmlenteties to remove/prevent cross-site-scripting attacks by completely removing any HTML and PHP tags it finds, as in:

```
$url_variable=$_GET['url_variable'];
$url_variable=strip_tags($url_variable);
```

This is to avoid mal program/script.
More secure will be handled by prepared statements, as in:

```
$stmt = $db_connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM $url_table WHERE url = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $url_variable);
```

Therefore, no need to use Quote in Mysqli since it has been used **prepared statements** and **bind the parameters to ensure** that you don't forget to escape a particular string which is led to a potential security problem.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't quote bind variables in prepared statements - the statement takes care of that for you:

```
$stmt = $db_connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM $url_table WHERE url = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $url_variable);
```